# research problem for undergraduate majoring in Computer Science and Mathematics

Tags: randomized-algorithms, randomness, matrices, random-walks

I am wondering if somebody can suggest a small research problem for undergraduate majoring in Computer Science and Mathematics. Would love to work with random matrices or wavelets.

Comment: Are you working on a course project or are you trying to start working on research problems in your free time?  :)

Comment: Thank you. This is Honors Project. But I would like to choose a topic which would allow me to open up new questions for the future research as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the providing more info!!  Let me think about it and see if any relevant problems come to mind.  :)

Comment: Did you talk to your advisors and/or professors?

Comment: My advisor wanted me to come up with a topic. I personally would love to do something like: 1) Data of businesses and what consisted of their success. What is the formula to success? e.g. loans, down payments, location, starting size, clientele, market niche, annual revenue;

Comment: 2) •Flight /Stock Price Prediction - Taking the known historical data on stocks or flights and using the data to analyze what impacted the increases and decreases (weather, laws, market demand, etc.) and predicting the future values. I have to figured if I can use random matrices or wavelets in those topics and how to properly post the problem. But I am not restricted to those topics, its just my idea...

Comment: Kaggle is a neat website with several datasets that are relevant to your interests.  I encourage you to take a look: https://www.kaggle.com/

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to connect it with random matrices or wavelets, but I encourage you to keep trying to find a connection.  :)

Comment: I work on problems related to automata and language theory and would have some problems to suggest, but it doesn't seem to directly align with your interests.  Regardless, please feel free to reach out to me anytime if you would like to talk.

Comment: Thank you so much,  Michael Wehar. I would love to work on your problems. I do not want to restrict myself only to mentioned by me and my supervisor topic. If you can please direct me on the topic of automata and language theory I would really appreciate and be happy to work on those problems :-) Thank you! :-)